# HttpURLConnection connection timeout not working

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

I have set connection timeout and Read timeout but still they are getting ignored, the request just stays on forever. How do I set a timeout such that the request gets cancelled if the timeout is reached ? 
This is my code snippet, appreciate your help.

```
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) saveURL.openConnection();
        // is output buffer writer
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("userid", id);

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jsonString);
        writer.flush();
        // json data
        writer.close();

        is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException soce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        soce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            if (null != urlConnection)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know its not working?

Comment: Because I set a timeout of 10s and timed it. It went on for over 2mins and finally succeeded. But the problem is that I have seen it go on for over 5mins and still not time out. I need to handle timeout gracefully so that the user can attempt upload another time when net speed is better.

Comment: I just meant that you don't seem to return anything to go by?

Comment: I am using the return stream that I read from the URL, that line of code was not shown here, that is all.

Comment: That could suggest that its not the request taking the time, but something else

Comment: The jsonString that I am trying to upload is actually about 2-4MB, so I am pretty sure that is what is taking the time. I want to do timeout and allow a "Retry" option to the user, instead of attempting for too long.

Comment: Well straight away that is your problem, that is a **massive** json string and will take much longer to process than upload

Comment: Exactly why I want the Timeout to be implemented on slower net connection.

Comment: but it has nothing to do with internet connection, you are processing way to much json

Comment: Sorry if I did not make the context clear, I need the timeout to cancel the upload of the large jsonString, if it exceeds a certain duration.

Comment: and that is what im saying, it is not the **network upload** of the string that is taking the time, it is the **creation of the json object**. You should never ever be creating a 2-4mb json string client side for upload, that just seems so very wrong

Comment: Not really, the creation is done in a separate method, that takes just a sec, I have timed it. It is the upload that takes time on slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best option, what I did was to set a Timer which I used to do a disconnection on HttpURLConnection once time was up. It seems to work fine so far. If anyone can point out the disadvantages of this approach and suggest a better way, I would appreciate it.